# Windows 10 internet connection fails regularly

Tags: networking, windows-10

Since I installed Windows 10 I have had weird internet failures.
It's bound to happen everytime I use the computer and the only way I'm able to "revert" it or "solve" it is by restarting my system.

I can't access any websites besides Google. And internet based applications like Discord, Hexchat etc is not working. And this just happens whenever, I can't link a specific action to this fault, I can be idle on the PC and suddenly it simply can't connect in any way besides to Google's domain.

Windows diagnostics can't find anything of course and I have updated all my Motherboards drivers.

I have no clue on what else to include into this post since I have no real clue as of what is happening or, why.

I also have tried multiple cables.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check is there any problem with DNS in your network? Try `ping`, `nslookup` and `tracert` command to check.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I have tried ping and nslookup on different sites and it all seems to work fine.

Comment: Have you upgraded to Windows 10 from a previous version of Windows? If so, then your driver might be outdated.

Comment: @iTechieGamer I have downloaded and installed all the latest drivers from my motherboards official support site.

Comment: Questions: (1) What is your network card and driver? (2) Do you have other connected devices and is this problem limited only to this one PC? (3) What is your router and its firmware version?

Comment: @harrymc I simply use the network socket from the motherboard. Well I have a set of different devices connected such as a external audio-interface and the regular stuff such as mouse and keyboard. The router and it's firmware I can't really tell. But this is only occuring on my PC, all other devices in the house is un-effected.

Comment: Two checks : (1) Can you connect an external network card via USB, to check if the problem is with your network card. (2) If the computer is still usable for you when booting in Safe Mode with Networking, see if this is still happening, to check if some installed product is causing the problem.

Comment: You should start a continuous ping (ping 8.8.8.8 -t) and when the internet stops working, if the ping continues working - Then you have a DNS issue - If the ping stops working, then we can look into the ethernet adapter on your PC followed by your router etc...

Comment: first things first, make sure everything is connected properly on the physical side... wires and such. Then check your network config after it fails (ipconfig /all) and edit your post or post it here with all the info.

Just a side note, check in your power management in your network card in device manager and uncheck your "authorize this computer to turn off this device"

Comment: It happened to me in Windows 8.1, and I fixed it by replacing my router. Really.

Comment: @Benni: Without answers to the above comments we cannot advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I may have found something that might be of use:
https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-can-only-connect-to-google-based-sites-mostly.1126777/

Here the guy had his IPv4 turned off for some reason, which limits the websites to Google's sites and a few others due to them being able to use IPv6 instead.

Check to see if your IPv4 is turned off as that seems to be the problem:
`Control Panel -> Network and Sharing -> Network adapter settings -> Right click on LAN/Wireless connection -> properties` You should be able to turn on IPv4 and IPv6 from this window.

Comment: Right now this is a link-only answer because the necessary parts of the solution are only available at the link. Please include the steps provided at the link to resolve the issue in the body of your post so that the link is not necessary to see and know the answer.

Comment: How do you check whether IPv4 is turned off? That is the information relevant to the answer you are trying to provide.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Though I checked my settings and both IPv4 and IPv6 are activated. Something I did find in the process is that the status of the Ethernet says that IPv6 connection is missing while IPv4 connection has "Internet". Not sure if this matters or is related in any way?

Comment: Then it might be a router problem perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a pattern and/or discard quite lot of things.

- Try **another device** on same network and connection type (wired, wireless) as your computer. If connection issues persist on this "new" device, then problem is on your network (router, switch). Also at same time that your computer.
- Boot your computer on **Safe mode with network** (pointed by @harrymc), if that works, just disable any kind of antivirus, and other applications that may interfere on your network (`start button -> taskmgr -> Start`).
- Boot your computer with a **LiveUSB (linux)**, and test. Working without loosing internet means your problem is on you OS (Win10), maybe network drivers, or some windows services.
- **Test your connection continuously**, as soon as you can't access any website do this commands (already mention by @Biswapriyo & @pythonian);

> ping -t 8.8.8.8
>
> pathping 8.8.8.8
>
> tracert 8.8.8.8

Change *8.8.8.8* for another IP like *185.60.216.35* (facebook) and repeat (just to ensure the problem is outside "google.com domain")

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has the following advice: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/10741/windows-10-fix-network-connection-issues

1. disable firewall/anti-virus and check. if still not working,
2. uninstall network adapter driver and restart.
3. <kbd>ctrl+shift+esc</kbd> for task manager and check for unruly startup programs or services and dismiss them
4. type "resmon" in start-search and hit enter to access resource monitor. check for any programs creating trouble for your RAM/CPU

My guess is that #1 and #2 should solve your issue.

If not, there must be some software shooting trouble sometime after system login (may be browser plugins or hidden trojans taking some time to kick-in). Try a different browser like [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en).